# Guide to acceptable "Live Bytes" of iOS6 app using MKMapView

Tags: ios6, mkmapview, instruments

I am looking to ensure my app does not consume too much memory on what are still fairly resource constrained devices.  Several days ago I was using *Instruments* to determine how much memory my app was using and I was getting around 4-8 megabytes for *Live Bytes*.  Today I run Instruments again and I am up around 30-35 megabytes for Live Bytes.  I don't believe I have made any significant changes to my code between these two times.

My app uses an `MKMapView` with a custom tile overlay.  I put off updating XCode for a fairly long time, and so I suspect that the difference may be that my iOS simulator was still using Google as opposed to Apple maps a few days ago, until I upgraded XCode.

As a small test, I created a new test app that just has an `MKMapView`, nothing else, and ran Instruments on it.  It is common for the Live Bytes of this app to be on the order of **50-90** megabytes, even though it has no custom code whatsoever - I just drag n' dropped the MKMapView on.

Whether this is intentional on Apple's behalf for the new maps to use this much memory I do not know.  Perhaps the map tiles are shared across apps and this is fine.  Either way though, it complicates coming up with a reasonable approximation for how many Live Bytes I can safely use, given that most earlier suggestions are on the order of 5-20MB, and Apple's MKMapView consumes 50-90MB on its own.

Is there another useful metric I can go by failing Live Bytes being any use now?

**Edit:** looks like for others this is a legitimate memory management problem and causing app crashes: [iOS6 MKMapView using a ton of memory, to the point of crashing the app, anyone else notice this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641658/ios6-mkmapview-using-a-ton-of-memory-to-the-point-of-crashing-the-app-anyone-e)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS6 MKMapView using a ton of memory, to the point of crashing the app, anyone else notice this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641658/ios6-mkmapview-using-a-ton-of-memory-to-the-point-of-crashing-the-app-anyone-e)