# Memory warnings with maps in iOS 6

Tags: ios6, mkmapview, didreceivememorywarning

I developed the app which used MKMapView runs both in iOS 5.x and 6.x devices, when I run the app in 5.x device, there are no memory warnings, but when I run in 6.x device, I found bunch of memory warnings mainly when pins are loaded on map and when map is zoomed in and out, panning means when perform any gesture operation on the map. I tried with the temporary solution found in SO answers by changing the map type when I receive memory warning but no luck, Please show me the way to solve these memory warnings. Thanks in advance

Comment: posting the warnings would be a great start.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641658/ios6-mkmapview-using-a-ton-of-memory-to-the-point-of-crashing-the-app-anyone-e/14198121#14198121

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the issue is with iOS 6 maps and its memory footprint. I did read about creating one instance of mapView in the AppDelegate should fix the issue however I am yet to try it.