# 300+ Markers on Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have an issue with Google Maps SDK v1.3.0 - When adding 300+ markers the map becomes unusable - impossible to zoom, pan and rotate without a 1-2 second delay and jitter.

Is this a known issue? Have other people experienced this also?

This is really causing major issues for our upcoming release and would be great to get a date for when this could possibly be fixed as we invested large chunk of time switching from Apple maps due to excessive memory usage 
[iOS6 MKMapView using a ton of memory, to the point of crashing the app, anyone else notice this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641658/ios6-mkmapview-using-a-ton-of-memory-to-the-point-of-crashing-the-app-anyone-e)

[EDIT]
I find this issue happens even after 100+ markers, and using the Google Map SDK sample apps the issue also arises.

Comment: How is the user going to use a screen with 300 markers? you should create clusters representing groups of markers, and let the user zoom in.

Comment: Yes, we already have a filter which reduces the amount the user can view at any one time, however we need the ability to give an overview of the entire area with all markers as it covers a large distance. 300+ doesn't seem excessive to me, this functionality was ok with older versions of Google Maps and also Apple Maps handle this very well.

Comment: I don't know about Google SDK, but on iOS 300 annotations use a small amount of memory unless you are using different images for the pins, or loading external data on each annotation object in advance. What I guess it uses a lot of memory is the cache for the map, which is normal because memory unused is memory wasted. That shouldn't worry you unless you get memory warnings due to a map cache malfunction.

Comment: Seems to be slightly improved in the Googles latest update [Version 1.3.1 - June 2013](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases#version_131_-_june_2013).

Comment: Same problem here. And clustering is not always a solution, that depends on the app. We really need to show markers without clustering and, on iPad, this is becoming a nightmare.

Comment: If you check the profiler, the method '[GMSEntityRendererView draw]' uses 95% of CPU in my case. So in the beginning I thought I was blocking somehow the UI Thread, but it is just a bug (must be).

Comment: I think it is a bug yes but I didn't report it yet, probably should do. I made the decision to stay with apple mapkit as it became impossible to navigate the google sdk and users would delete the app with frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed in the latest version - Version 1.4.1 - August 2013. 
See the resolved issues of the release notes:
**Performance improvements when using hundreds of GMSMarkers.**