# Stop iOS 7 MKMapView from leaking memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, mkmapview

I've noticed that my app leaks memory, but if I take the `MKMapView` out the memory problem goes away.

To test the theory, I made a dead simple project that has a view that pushes a view with a `MKMapView` in it and pops and pushes. Nothing more. No code in the view controllers, everthing done via storyboard.

If I go back and forth to the map view, it starts about 3MB after doing pushing and popping the view with the map in it this about 15 times the memory is around 230MB.

Anyone else seen this?   Seems like a pretty big bug. Is there a different way to use `MKMapView` that will prevent it from leaking so much?

[image]

Comment: I see this behavior in my App too and for me the question is clear: What is happening here? Is this a real memory leak (it seems so) and has someone figured out what is going wrong and how to fix.

Comment: Try to remove the MKMapView in viewDidDisappear method, example : [self.outMapView removeFromSuperview]; self.outMapView = nil;

Comment: probably should log a radar ticket.

Comment: search and you find dozens of these questions here and on other forums - file a radar. nothing else you can do since the map is broken

Comment: Still broken in iOS 9.x. I solved it by storing a reference to MKMapView in a static variabled and reusing the same Map over and over again.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35601554/723276

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS6 MKMapView using a ton of memory, to the point of crashing the app, anyone else notice this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641658/ios6-mkmapview-using-a-ton-of-memory-to-the-point-of-crashing-the-app-anyone-e)

Answer (score 18):

I had faced the same issue and (thanks to Stackoverflow) fixed it by changing `MKMapType` in  `viewWillDisappear` and deallocating/setting its delegate to nil.As it still sends message to delegates.
This is documented in MKMapViewDelegate Protocol Reference:

> Before releasing an MKMapView object for which you have set a
>   delegate, remember to set that object’s delegate property to nil. One
>   place you can do this is in the dealloc method where you dispose of
>   the map view

.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [self applyMapViewMemoryFix];

}

- (void)applyMapViewMemoryFix{

switch (self.mkMapView.mapType) {
    case MKMapTypeHybrid:
    {
        self.mkMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    }

        break;
    case MKMapTypeStandard:
    {
        self.mkMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
    }

        break;
    default:
        break;
}
self.mkMapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
self.mkMapView.delegate = nil;
[self.mkMapView removeFromSuperview];
self.mkMapView = nil;
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't help. Still leaking.

Comment: Yes, it's also still leaking for me. I have the map view in a `UICollcetionViewCell` so I can't call this code from `viewWillDisappear`. Calling it in the cell's `deinit` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Swift Version:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated:Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.applyMapViewMemoryFix()
}

func applyMapViewMemoryFix() {
    switch (self.mapView.mapType) {
    case MKMapType.hybrid:
        self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
    case MKMapType.standard:
        self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.hybrid
    default:
        break
    }
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = false
    self.mapView.delegate = nil
    self.mapView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.mapView = nil
}
```

Comment: I still have memory issue in iOS 8.3/8.4 even though I implemented your solution

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I have found is to have an instance of MKMapView in your delegate, you will allocate it only once.

Then anytime you need a MapView, you just use the one from the delegate.

In my case i needed to clean the annotations from it as soon as the view willDisappear ( to not have older annotations on the map ).

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
      AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
          if (!delegate.appModel.mapView)
             delegate.appModel.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
      self.mapView = delegate.appModel.mapView;
      [self.mapView setFrame:self.view.frame];
      [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
      [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
   }

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
    for (id<MKOverlay> overlay in self.mapView.overlays) {
        [self.mapView removeOverlay:overlay];
    }
}
```

Comment: A static variable will do (instead of storing it in an application delegate variable)