# Makpit Memory Leak

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I tried a lot of solutions but even in actual device, memory consumption is  very high. When secondview is dismissed first time, memory doesnot decrease like its increases. The memory usage after dismissing secondview depends on how much area user discovered in map.
Here is my code.

First view controller

```
import UIKit

import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    private let currentColor = UIColor(red: 234/255.0, green: 128/255.0, blue: 16/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        let button = buttonLoader(y: 7*self.view.frame.height/16, text: "trigger")
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }
    private func buttonLoader(y:CGFloat,text:String)->UIButton{
        let Label = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: y , width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height/8))
        Label.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
        Label.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mapOpener), for: .touchUpInside)
        Label.setTitleColor(currentColor, for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(Label)
        return Label
    }

    @objc func mapOpener(){
        let newView = SecondViewController()
        newView.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.present(newView, animated: true, completion: nil)  
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

SecondViewController

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var map :MKMapView!
    var saverButton : UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        saveButtonLoader()
        mapLoader()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func mapLoader(){
        map = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: view.frame.size.width, height:  self.view.frame.size.height-64))
        map.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        map.isZoomEnabled = true
        map.isScrollEnabled = true
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.userTrackingMode = .follow
        view.addSubview(map)
    }
    func saveButtonLoader()  {
        saverButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 4*view.frame.size.width/5, y: 20, width: view.frame.size.width/5, height:  44))
        saverButton.setTitle("Finish", for: .normal)
        saverButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(finishButtonAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        saverButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        saverButton.isEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(saverButton)
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated:Bool){
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.applyMapViewMemoryFix()
    }
    func applyMapViewMemoryFix(){

        map.delegate = nil
        removeOldAnnotations()
        map.removeFromSuperview()
        map = nil

    }

    func removeOldAnnotations(){
        for annotation in map.annotations{
            map.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
    @objc func finishButtonAction(sender:UIButton!) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your "Memory leak Solution" (`removeOldAnnotations`) fix the problem?

Comment: Noop, That part is what I tried to overcome this problem but still its same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MKMapView using a lot of memory each time i load its view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417350/mkmapview-using-a-lot-of-memory-each-time-i-load-its-view)